# Compare two ArrayList in a two way comparison?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, arraylist

I have a class called `Task` which I cannot touch because it's a legacy code and I have two `ArrayList` made up of `Task` class which I need to compare. Items can be in any order or there can be duplicates as well in the ArrayList.

What is the best way to compare two `ArrayList` which has object in it and print out the missing elements as well which are not present in either of the list. Is below code is the right and efficient way to do it? I cannot use any external library for this.

I need to compare my two array list in a two way comparison.

- If data is in source but not in actual, then return false and print out missing elements.
- If data is in actual but not in source, then return false as well and print out missing elements.

Below is my code:

```
  public static boolean compare(List<Task> source, List<Task> actual) {
    List<Task> matchedTasksList = new ArrayList<Task>();
    List<Task> differedTasksList = new ArrayList<Task>();

    List<Task> copyOfSource = new ArrayList<>(source);
    List<Task> copyOfActual = new ArrayList<>(actual);
    for (Task o : actual) {
      if (!copyOfSource.remove(o)) {
        differedTasksList.add(o);
        System.out.println("Task not present: " + o.toString());
        return false;
      } else {
        matchedTasksList.add(o);
      }
    }
    matchedTasksList.clear();
    for (Task o : source) {
      if (!copyOfActual.remove(o)) {
        differedTasksList.add(o);
        System.out.println("Task not present: " + o.toString());
        return false;
      } else {
        matchedTasksList.add(o);
      }
    }
    return (differedTasksList.size() == 0) ? true : false;
  }
```

Comment: You wrote that "there can be duplicates as well in the ArrayList."  Does that mean one ArrayList could contain the same Task multiple times?  Are those the same Task object, or different Task objects with equivalent data?  Also, if `source` contains a Task twice, and `actual` contains it once, does that mean `actual` is "missing" that Task once?

Comment: It's a different task object with equivalent data and yes actual is missing that task once.. And it has to be two way comparison as well.

Comment: Use HashSets instead of ArrayLists (more efficient + removal of duplicates) and use the methods retainAll and removeAll of the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public boolean compare(List<Task> source, List<Task> actual) {
    Set<Task> intersection = new HashSet<>(source);
    Set<Task> sourceDifference = new HashSet<>(source);
    Set<Task> actualDifference = new HashSet<>(actual);

    intersection.retainAll(actualDifference);

    sourceDifference.removeAll(intersection);
    for (Task t: sourceDifference) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Task %s not present in actual", t));
    }

    actualDifference.removeAll(intersection);
    for (Task t: actualDifference) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Task %s not present in source", t));
    }

    return sourceDifference.isEmpty() && actualDifference.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: You could consider using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html instead of HashSet if the order in which the tasks are logged is important

Comment: How we will use LinkedHashSet here? Can you update accordingly so that I can understand?

Comment: Instead of
`Set<Task> sourceDifference = new HashSet<>(source);
Set<Task> actualDifference = new HashSet<>(actual);`
you write
`Set<Task> sourceDifference = new LinkedHashSet<>(source);
Set<Task> actualDifference = new LinkedHashSet<>(actual);`
Only do this if the ordering of the elements matters, because a HashSet is more efficient than a LinkedHashSet for insertions and removals

Answer (score 0):

it seems like that function only prints first missing element, but as I understood you need to print all missing elements and return false? if so try in this way:

```
public boolean compare(List<Task> source, List<Task> actual) {
       List<Task> copyOfSource = new ArrayList<>(source);
       copyOfSource.removeAll(actual);
       copyOfSource.forEach(o -> System.out.println("Task not present:    "+o.toString()));
       return copyOfSource.isEmpty();
  }
```

Comment: I am working with Java 7, can you edit it accordingly? And does it do two way comparion as well as I mentioned in my question? See my updated question.

Comment: This will fail if source has 4  elements and actual has 5 elements.

Comment: I like @toongeorges's answer